# CMake escaping variable for configure

Tags: linux, cmake

Currently I am setting RPATH using following syntax:

```
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH   "${CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH}:$ORIGIN/../lib")
```

It is working for the binary build using CMake.
The problem is that it is not working for a third party binary I am building using CMake using their auto-configure script. I am using the following command for configure:

```
add_custom_target(
                  third_party_bin ALL
                  COMMAND ./configure
                  --with-ld-opt=\"-Wl,-rpath,${CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH}\"
                  --prefix=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
                  )
```

The Makefile generated by third path configure look like:

```
" -Wl,-rpath,':RIGIN/../lib' -lstdc++"
```

I think I need to escape `${CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH}` correctly. 
I also tried using options like:

```
add_custom_target(
                  third_party_bin ALL
                  COMMAND ./configure
                  --with-ld-opt=\"-Wl,-rpath,\$\$ORIGIN/../lib\"
                  --prefix=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
                  )
```

and

```
add_custom_target(
                  third_party_bin ALL
                  COMMAND ./configure
                  --with-ld-opt=\"-Wl,-rpath,\\$\$ORIGIN/../lib\"
                   --prefix=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
                  )
```

but nothing works.

What is the correct way to escape  values?

Answer (score 1):

`add_custom_target` accepts a `VERBATIM` argument. According to the documentation:

> If `VERBATIM` is given then all arguments to the commands will be
>          escaped properly for the build tool so that the invoked command
>          receives each argument unchanged.  Note that one level of escapes is
>          still used by the CMake language processor before `add_custom_target`
>          even sees the arguments.  Use of `VERBATIM` is recommended as it enables
>          correct behavior.  When `VERBATIM` is not given the behavior is platform
>          specific because there is no protection of tool-specific special
>          characters.

Answer (score -1):

If I am reading this correctly, you are looking to escape the shell from interpreting the $ variables...  If so, use single quotes (') instead of doubles (").  The shell doesn't interpret variables wrapped in single quotes.